# Mysql hierarchy - check if node is parent

Tags: mysql, hierarchy

I have a users table in this format:

```
|   ID   |   PARENT  |
|    1   |           |
|    2   |     1     |
|    3   |     1     | 
|    4   |     3     |
|    5   |     3     |
|    6   |     5     |
```

I wanted to create a query to verify if X is parent of Y. The examples i've found didn't help much as they don't work very well in multilevel hierarchy.
Thanks for the help!

EDIT : the output can be the list of all parent of a node and in PHP I can check if the id is in the list.

I have tried this query:

```
select  id,
        parent_id 
from    (select * from users
         order by parent_id, id) users_sorted,
        (select @pv := '200911') initialisation
where   find_in_set(parent_id, @pv) > 0
and     @pv := concat(@pv, ',', id);
```

But it only works for ids that are superior to the one we are searching for. I have a special case where the parent id is superior to his child's

Comment: Can you let us know what you want by way of sample input and output?

Comment: sure, i have edited the question. The query can retrieve the full list of parents of a node for instance

Comment: Google for recursive hierarchical queries in MySQL.  This question is a duplicate but I won't mark it as such.

Comment: For performing this kind of query efficiently, the phrase you need is "modified preorder traversal" - that should help you find plenty of articles on the table structure you need.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database

Comment: @PaulDixon, using that approach I would have to update the whole table every time I insert a new node?

Comment: Yes - but an insertion typically involves just one extra query to increment the right value in affected rows.

Comment: i was trying to avoid that from the start, but you are right. I'm going to give it a go